# Valgrind Error: Freeing memory in the scope of function in C

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, free

I am receiving an error when using valgrind:

```
==696839== HEAP SUMMARY:
==696839==     in use at exit: 136 bytes in 1 blocks
==696839==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 5 frees, 12,624 bytes allocated
==696839== 
==696839== 136 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==696839==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==696839==    by 0x109A35: insert_word_into_table (dictionary.c:57)
==696839==    by 0x109BD9: dict_insert (dictionary.c:82)
==696839==    by 0x109606: main (spell_check.c:91)
==696839== 
==696839== LEAK SUMMARY:
==696839==    definitely lost: 136 bytes in 1 blocks
==696839==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==696839==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==696839==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==696839==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Here is a basic, minimal version of the function where the error is occurring; I am iterating through an array of linked lists.

```
int insert_word_into_table(table_t *table, const char *word){
    int hsh_code = hash_code(word);
    int duplicateWordFlag = 0;

    //initialize the new node for the word
    list_node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));//line 57 that error is referring to
    //printf("%lu", sizeof(list_node_t)); checking the size, it is 136 bytes

    if (table->array[hsh_code] == NULL) {//if nothing is in the array
        table->array[hsh_code] = newNode;
        table->array[hsh_code]->next = NULL;
        strcpy(table->array[hsh_code]->word, word);
    } else {//if there is a node there
        list_node_t* i = table->array[hsh_code];
        while (i->next != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(word, i->word) == 0){
                duplicateWordFlag = -1;
            }
            i = i->next;
        }
        i->next = malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));
        strcpy(i->next->word, word);
        i->next->next = NULL;
    }
    return duplicateWordFlag;
}
```

I attempted to free the memory in the two spot I malloc'd in the function but that did not work either. I am a bit confused; if the memory is allocated in a function is it not freed when the program leaves the function, or is it on the heap? In any case at the end of my whole program I free the memory for the whole array of linked lists which I thought would take care of it.

Any advice or thoughts would be great. Thanks!

### Edit 2 (the plot thickens):

So I changed the function to instead use

```
i->next = newNode;//new way
```

and the error persisted

This is how I am freeing memory, this function is called at the very end of my program:

```
void dict_free(dictionary_t *dict) {
    free(dict->table->array);//base array of linked lists
    free(dict->table);
    free(dict);
}
```

### Edit 3: Solution

This fixed it; I guess freeing using the pointer to the struct was not enough and I had to free all the nodes.

```
void dict_free(dictionary_t *dict) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dict->table->length; i++) {
        free(dict->table->array[i]);
    }
    free(dict->table->array);
    free(dict->table);
    free(dict);
}
```

### Update/Edit 4: (Realizing the magnitude of my error) Trying to free everything for real.

I realize now that I am not freeing everything (as some pointed out).

In my previous solution while it solved the immediate issue, it was not freeing all the memory (again, as some pointed out).

Here is my solution to iterate through all of the linked list and free all the memory that was allocated.

```
//free the table; a structure that is an array of linked lists
void table_free(table_t *table) {
        list_node_t *node;
        list_node_t *tempNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < table->length; i++) {
            if (table->array[i] != NULL) {
                if (table->array[i]->next == NULL) {//if only one node in linked list
                    free(table->array[i]);
                    continue;
                } else {
                    node = table->array[i];
                    while(node->next != NULL) {
                        tempNode = node->next;
                        free(node);
                        node = tempNode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < table->length; i++) {
            if (table->array[i] == NULL) { //free the spots I missed
                free(table->array[i]);
            }
        }
        free(table->array);
        free(table);
}

void dict_free(dictionary_t *dict) {
    //old way not freeing everything
    // for (int i = 0; i < dict->table->length; i++) {
    //     free(dict->table->array[i]);
    // }
    // free(dict->table->array);
    // free(dict->table);
    // free(dict);    

    //new attempt
    table_free(dict->table);
    free(dict);
}
```

I feel confident that this would free everything, based on what others were suggesting. But I am still receiving valgrind errors:

```
==4020884== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4020884==     in use at exit: 97,376 bytes in 716 blocks
==4020884==   total heap usage: 8,606 allocs, 7,890 frees, 1,209,040 bytes allocated
==4020884== 
==4020884== 97,376 bytes in 716 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4020884==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4020884==    by 0x109B32: insert_word_into_table (dictionary.c:56)
==4020884==    by 0x109C8E: dict_insert (dictionary.c:97)
==4020884==    by 0x10A16A: read_dict_from_text_file (dictionary.c:245)
==4020884==    by 0x10981A: main (spell_check.c:142)
```

My big question (as this is a larger program), **if I free everything I allocated solely at the end is that good practice and sufficient to freeing all the memory?** I allocate memory inside of various functions without freeing it.

Thank you to the community for their patience and helping me solve this.

Comment: In the `else` case you don't use the `newNode` you unconditionally allocated. Instead you create a new and independent node object and use that, leaving `newNode` to be leaked.

Comment: So change `i->next = malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));` to `i->next = newNode;`

Comment: You also check for duplicates, but you still insert the new duplicate node into the hash-table. Hash-tables typically doesn't include duplicates. And if you want to do it (it's still useful in some use-cases) then I recommend you use a counter in the nodes, instead of creating a brand new node.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the line to:
```
i->next = newNode;//new way
```
However, the error persists? I tried to free(newNode) at the end as well, which also failed. 

Also, @Some programmer dude thanks for pointing out the duplication bug.

Comment: Can we also see how you're inserting nodes and freeing memory, please? Show us a basic `main` function that inserts nodes and frees the list and exhibits the problem.

Comment: I'm sure the solution you show did solve the issue as you observed it.  I'm equally sure that it is insufficient in the event that you get multiple words assigned to the same hash bucket.  If you want to free all allocated memory then every single `malloc()` call must be paired with its own corresponding `free()` call.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that's a good point. I don't think that I will have to worry about multiple words in the context of what I am doing. However, I appreciate you being so thorough.

Comment: Since each element in `dict->table->array` is a list, you need to free the nodes of the lists too. Your "solution" only free the first node in the list.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I realize how my initial solution is not sufficient now… I feel confident that my new code (please see the update) reaches all nodes, the array, the table, and finally the dictionary, but my code still has memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the memory is allocated in a function is it not freed when the program leaves the function, or is it on the heap?

Memory allocated dynamically (such as via `malloc`) remains allocated until it is explicitly freed.  "Heap" in this sense is not a C-language concept, but generally, yes, the memory is allocated on the heap on systems where that is meaningful.

> In any case at the end of my whole program I free the memory for the whole array of linked lists which I thought would take care of it.

And that some memory does not get freed that way is a sign of a memory leak, which I presume is exactly the sort of thing you wanted Valgrind to detect for you.  It appears to me that the problem is that the node you allocate at dictionary.c:57 is linked into the list only if `table->array[hsh_code] == NULL` evaluates to 1.  Otherwise, the function returns without freeing it or retaining any pointer to it.  This is a classic memory leak.

Note that in the other branch, you allocate another node.  It looks like you could instead use the one you've already allocated, which might solve your leak problem.

---

The code now shown for how you free the hash table shows an additional deficiency. This ...

> ```
>     free(dict->table->array);//base array of linked lists
> ```

... frees only the array wherein the node pointers are stored, not any of the allocated nodes themselves.  Based on your `insert_word_into_table()` function, before freeing the array, you need *at least* to iterate over all the hash buckets, and for each one, free *every* linked list node associated with that bucket.  Maybe something like this:

```
for (size_t bucket = 0; bucket < NUMBER_OF_BUCKETS; bucket++) {
    for (list_node_t *node = dict->table->array[bucket]; node; ) {
        list_node_t *next = node->next;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @John Bollinger. I changed it to use the newNode that I already allocated but the same error still persists. Additional thoughts?

Comment: There is not enough information to say, @tothemax, but I'm inclined to think that there is a separate issue in the code you have not shown us.  Perhaps in the code that frees the hash table at the end.  Or if, contrary to what you have shown, you avoided inserting a node in the case of a duplicate word, then you might in that event leak the allocated node.

Comment: This is a great thought. I tried to free the node in the case of a duplicate word as well, just before the "duplicateWordFlag = -1;" line but that did not seem to work either. I updated the post to show how I am freeing the memory at the end, if that helps.

Comment: @tothemax, added commentary about your method of freeing the nodes.

Answer (score -1):

In your function you are using two correct syntaxes to declare a pointer to
a list_node_t:

```c
list_node_t *newNode
```

and

```c
list_node_t* i
```

For best code readability, use only one of them at least in the whole code of the function, otherwise it is being a little distracting.
One of the best practices when dealing with memory allocation is to verify if it succeeded, take a look at the malloc documentation.

```
$ man malloc
```

Is highly recommended to check for the return value of a malloc call and not assuming it, the handy way is to treat the case a NULL pointer is returned.

```c
list_node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));
if (newNode == NULL) {
  //no memory allocated
  //do something
}
```

Saying "minimum version of the function" is too wide, in the case of memory leaks, all the code of functions susceptible to modify the data structure (in ascendant priority : table_t, list_node_t) or any other method of taking trace of the allocated memory (and from which is meant to be accessed from) is needed to be reviewed, except printf statements.

I suggest you to use a code beautifier (I'm using uncrustify).